# book to learn how to admin a debian box?

Tags: debian

I want to learn the ins/outs of debian, in order to provide hosting for customers (I don't plan on doing it actually, but I want to know how its done etc).

So can you guys recommend a book that goes over debian as an OS, and common techniques scripts that help automating and keep a server running?

I am currently reading the a linux tutorial on got on the net (free), its a pdf. RUT OR RTE or something (its on my other pc)

Answer (score 1):

For a useful recommendation, I think you would need to tell us about your current level in things such as Networking, Scripting, and General *nix.

A book on a particular Linux distribution I don't think is that important, unless you are already quite familiar with Linux / Scripting / Networking / Standard Services (DNS / Email / Web (Apache)) already.  I would focus on these, and then Debian will just end up being 'variations on a theme'.  As you learn this stuff, you can just practice on a Debian / Ubuntu box.

If you are already at the above level, someone else might have good recommendation for you, I haven't read anything specific to what you are asking.

Comment: kyle, then is there a general book that you would suggest? there are tons, so I would rather read one that others think is a great book.

Comment: Some are:  Scripting:  Reilly Basic Shell Scripting, Networking: Sybex CCNA for (Cisco, but a good networking introduction) and TCP/IP illustrated, *nix: Introduction to Advanced Programing in the Unix Environment.  For general administration, Essential System Administration and System Performance Tuning (both O'Reilly) are good.  For a single, gentle introductory book I am not the best person to ask as I just played with Linux a lot a relatively young age.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the official [Debian Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/index.en.html)? It has general coverage of almost every topic you need to get started. For more specific information you can consult the documentation of the package in question. I used this for many years when I was first starting out.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing Debian is you have to get used to aptitude/apt-get commands to install/update/remove packages.

Not many books were made for Debian, but I recommend www.togaware.com/linux/survivor which is a Linux beginner's guide with more focus on Debian and its packages, commands, etc.

If your Linux knowledge is quite well, I suggest subscribing to Debian's mailing list -- I, personally have picked up quite a few things from there.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently reading this book, [LPIC-1: Linux Professional Institute Certification Study Guide: (Exams 101 and 102), 2nd Edition](http://www.sybex.com/WileyCDA/SybexTitle/LPIC-1-Linux-Professional-Institute-Certification-Study-Guide-Exams-101-and-102-2nd-Edition.productCd-0470404833.html) (and studying for LPIC-1 while I'm at it.)

It's not exactly what you want--the material is for Linux Professional Institute Certification. It is *not* Debian-specific, but *sections* are (the package management track, for example, has examples for Debian & derivatives, as well as RPM-based distributions, etc.)

It's very informative and covers quite a bit of ground but it's not *specific to Debian* and won't cover tiny nuances that you may be looking for.